# vim "Unknown function: omni#cpp#maycomplete#Dot"

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

I've switched my old .vimrc over to a new installation of Arch Linux and get the following error whenever I type '.' (period) while editing a .cpp file

```
E117: Unknown function: omni#cpp#maycomplete#Dot
E15: Invalid expression: omni#cpp#maycomplete#Dot()
```

At first I hadn't explicitly installed any autocompletion plugins. After that I tried installing a couple but at this point it is too much effort so I removed everything but still get that error.

Does anyone know how I can just make the error go away without bothering with autocompletion plugins? I'd like to be able to type '.' again :)

FYI, here's my ~.vimrc

```
" .vimrc
" See: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html for details

" For multi-byte character support (CJK support, for example):
"set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp936,big5,euc-jp,euc-kr,gb18030,latin1

set tabstop=4       " Number of spaces that a <Tab> in the file counts for.

set shiftwidth=4    " Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent.

"set expandtab       " Use the appropriate number of spaces to insert a <Tab>.
                    " Spaces are used in indents with the '>' and '<' commands
                    " and when 'autoindent' is on. To insert a real tab when
                    " 'expandtab' is on, use CTRL-V <Tab>.

"set smarttab        " When on, a <Tab> in front of a line inserts blanks
                    " according to 'shiftwidth'. 'tabstop' is used in other
                    " places. A <BS> will delete a 'shiftwidth' worth of space
                    " at the start of the line.

set showcmd         " Show (partial) command in status line.

set number          " Show line numbers.

set showmatch       " When a bracket is inserted, briefly jump to the matching
                    " one. The jump is only done if the match can be seen on the
                    " screen. The time to show the match can be set with
                    " 'matchtime'.

set hlsearch        " When there is a previous search pattern, highlight all
                    " its matches.

set incsearch       " While typing a search command, show immediately where the
                    " so far typed pattern matches.

set ignorecase      " Ignore case in search patterns.

set smartcase       " Override the 'ignorecase' option if the search pattern
                    " contains upper case characters.

set backspace=2     " Influences the working of <BS>, <Del>, CTRL-W
                    " and CTRL-U in Insert mode. This is a list of items,
                    " separated by commas. Each item allows a way to backspace
                    " over something.

set autoindent      " Copy indent from current line when starting a new line
                    " (typing <CR> in Insert mode or when using the "o" or "O"
                    " command).

set textwidth=0    " Maximum width of text that is being inserted. A longer
                    " line will be broken after white space to get this width.

set formatoptions=c,q,r,t " This is a sequence of letters which describes how
                    " automatic formatting is to be done.
                    "
                    " letter    meaning when present in 'formatoptions'
                    " ------    ---------------------------------------
                    " c         Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting
                    "           the current comment leader automatically.
                    " q         Allow formatting of comments with "gq".
                    " r         Automatically insert the current comment leader
                    "           after hitting <Enter> in Insert mode. 
                    " t         Auto-wrap text using textwidth (does not apply
                    "           to comments)

set ruler           " Show the line and column number of the cursor position,
                    " separated by a comma.

set background=dark " When set to "dark", Vim will try to use colors that look
                    " good on a dark background. When set to "light", Vim will
                    " try to use colors that look good on a light background.
                    " Any other value is illegal.

set mouse=a         " Enable the use of the mouse.

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
let g:Imap_UsePlaceHolders = 0
let g:Tex_EnvironmentMaps = 0
let g:Tex_FontMaps = 0
let g:Tex_SectionMaps = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeyBS = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeyQuote = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeySpace = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeyDot = 0
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats = 'pdf dvi'
let g:Tex_EscapeChars = '\'

" arduino syntax
autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead *.pde setlocal ft=arduino

call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
```

And, since I have pathogen installed, the contents of ~/.vim/bundle

```
[~]$ ls ~/.vim/bundle/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 6 ryantr ryantr 40 Jul  3 23:01 netrw
```

Comment: You have a nicely commented .vimrc; that's great!

Comment: Heh, I wish I could take credit but I copied that from somewhere. I'm way too lazy to do that on my own. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a *filetype plugin* for `cpp` provides an insert-mode mapping for `.`; check the output of `:scriptnames` for files containing `.../ftplugin/cpp...`, or `:verbose imap .` in a corresponding buffer.

If you cannot find the culprit (an `inoremap <buffer> .`) there, a

```
:autocmd FileType cpp iunmap <buffer> .
```

in your `~/.vimrc` should get rid of the broken mapping.

Comment: Doh! I had also copied a mksession file for the project I'm working on and that had the errant mappings in there. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [OmniCppComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520) is not installed properly.